# MVC main menu and selected submenu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a menu for the MVC music store application. Currently it looks like this
[image: As you can see I have the index view CSS selected not the About view]

As you can see I have the Home sub level menu selected when in fact I am on the About View.

I used Darins example for the main menu and created a helper class which looks like this.

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
        string linkText, string actionName,
        string controllerName)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    //modified this to work whenever a view of the controller is selected
    //if (actionName == currentAction && controllerName == currentController)
    if (controllerName == currentController)
    {
        return helper.ActionLink(
            linkText,
            actionName,
            controllerName,
            null,
            new
            {
                @class = "active"
            });
    }
    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}
```

Note I did slightly change the code as I wasn't interested in action name. I found this limited me and the main menu wouldn't add the active CSS state where I wanted.

So that works perfect for the top level menu however I am a little stuck with the sublevel menu. My html consists of 2 UL tags like

```html
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.MenuLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.MenuLink("Store", "Index", "Store")</li>
            <li>@Html.MenuLink("Cart", "Index", "ShoppingCart")</li>
           <li>@Html.MenuLink("Admin", "Index", "StoreManager")</li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="page-subheader">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sub-nav">
            <ul>
             <li>@Html.SubMenuLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.SubMenuLink("About", "Index", "Home/About")</li>
           @*     <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Content("~")">Index</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/About")">About</a></li>*@
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <input placeholder="Search..." type="text" name="q" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Pretty standard HTML I have also tried to create another helper like:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString SubMenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, 
        string linkText, string actionName,
        string controllerName)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    if (controllerName == currentController)
    {
        return helper.ActionLink(
            linkText,
            actionName,
            controllerName,
            null,
            new
            {
                @class = "active"
            });
    }
    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}
```

But I don't really know what to do next. If I put a break point on the code I can see `currentAction` is been returned as `About` and `currentController` is been returned as `Home`, I'm just a little unsure how to add the logic apply the active CSS class to the submenu.

Can some please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the original method unchanged. I am doing exactly the same.

One note of caution. I've started using Areas and these methods no longer work so well.

```
public static MvcHtmlString SubMenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName,
                                       string controllerName)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    if (controllerName == currentController && actionName == currentAction)
    {
        return helper.ActionLink(
            linkText,
            actionName,
            controllerName,
            null,
            new
            {
                @class = "active"
            });
    }
    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}
```

Comment: I'm using something very similar, and have started using Areas as well.  How did you update this to work with areas?

Comment: Is it still same for using Areas? How did you fix this?